# Sudden compilation error during maven release

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have recently started having trouble releasing a maven project which has worked fine for a long time now. The project consists of several modules with a structure looking something like:

```
project_server
  project_webserver
  project_qp
    project_qp_ingr
  project_repo
    project_repo_ingr
```

Both modules project_qp and project_repo are dependent on project_webserver with ${project.version} references.

The project is build using Jenkins and everything works fine when I am building snapshot builds. 
When I try to build a release with version 3.1-RC1 in a maven release build configuration with the options/goals "-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform -e", everything works fine in the "clean, verify" phase, but in the "deploy, site-deploy", project_repo suddenly doesn't compile.

The compilation errors consist of the module not finding classes from the project_webserver module. However, the project_qp_ingr module has already been built and is working fine.

All of this suggests to me that there is something wrong with the reference from project_repo_ingr to project_webserver but since the project builds fine when I am building snapshot releases.

The pom of project_repo_ingr looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>project_repo_ingr</artifactId>
<name>project_repo_ingr</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.apptus.ecom</groupId>
    <artifactId>project_repo</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.apptus.ecom</groupId>
        <artifactId>project_webserver</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.apptus.ecom</groupId>
        <artifactId>project_webserver</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I have omitted some dependencies but that is pretty much it. Both the module project_repo_ingr and project_qp_ingr have the dependency to both the regular artifact and the test-jar.

I use Java 6, Maven 2 and Jenkins 1.436 with M2 Release Plugin 0.8.1.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have torn my hair all day long about this.

Update:
The changes that I have made since the last time this worked is branching the svn repo from the trunk to a release branch. The jenkins job in trunk has been copied into one for the branch and the svn path is changed. I have also updated the  part of the project_server pom.

Comment: Please tell us about the changes "you" made since the code last worked.

Comment: Have you changed the version number during the branch ? Have you used the release plugin to branch or manually via SVN ?

Comment: I branched manually using SVN and kept the version number from trunk. After branching, I updated the version numbers in the trunk.